# How do I make a RichTextArea in Google Web Toolkit(GWT) Selectable/Highlight-able by a mouse but not Editable/Modifiable?

Tags: java, gwt, panel, highlighting, rtf

I'm currently making a GWT project where I display some HTML in a `RichTextArea`, and I want the `RichTextArea` to be selectable/highlight-able by a mouse but NOT be editable/modifiable by the user. In addition to this question, could you also tell me how to retrieve some highlighted text in string from without me having to add a text-background toolbar, which, after highlighting a text from the `RichTextArea`, you change the color of the text-background, upon which, you add a separate periodically looping thread which checks to see when the text-background changes substantially from white (or a native color of the webpage) and finally extracting the string whose text-background color differs as the selected text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really hate to give any pointers without explanation but i think your requirements are bigger ::: so --->

http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~RichTextArea

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/RichTextArea.htm